# How to understand the quadratic form of kinetic energy with $\dot{q}$ coefficients?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, mass, coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus

Kinetic energy can be written as:

$$ T=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\alpha=1}^K\sum_{\beta=1}^K a_{\alpha \beta}(q)\dot{q}^\alpha \dot{q}^\beta$$

Where the object $a_{\alpha \beta}$ is a certain tensor. How to understand and visualise this equation? Why write it like this?

Comment: As soon as you use non-cartesian coordinates you get this kind of expression for the kinetic energy, e.g. in spherical coordinates: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Kinematics). It can also show up with some kinds of constraints.

Answer (score 1):

Think to it as the kinetic energy of the system. The tensor acting on velocities is some sort of generalized mass for a bunch of bodies.

Answer (score 0):

Kinetic energy is a positive quadratic in the velocity of the points, and angular velocity of the rigid bodies.

Velocities and angular velocities are linear in the $\dot{q}_i$ (affine if the coordinates explicitly depends on time).

Thus, the kinetic energy is quadratic in the $\dot{q}_i$ as well.